# Google authentication screen on click of an app in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, google-authentication, google-authenticator

I am building an app in Angular 6 + PWA. I have to implement Google Authentication for logging in. The google login screen should be the first screen when we click on the app icon. I don't want the screen where Google button appears for and on its click the login screen appears. Post successful login, landing page will appear. From what i could gather, only on click of the following button, will the logins screen appears

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

When we click on this button, control is given to **onSignIn()** and then the flow is carried on. I want this function to be called on **ngOnInit()** of angular 
 **app.component.ts** as it is the root component. Basically i don't want the following:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

and yet i want to call its method onSignIn()

How can i achieve this?

Comment: If I've understood right, you could simply use `this.onSignIn()` on the `ngOnInit()` of your app component. Obviously, you will have to declare the function inside the app component

Comment: this.onSignIn() is not a class method, neither is it triggered by the (click) function of angular, so we can't configure onSignIn() (which is a google method) inside ngOnInit()

Answer (score -1):

In my AuthService I have a method that looks like this:

```
googleLogin() {
const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}
```

In the component you want to use this you could do this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 
'@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 
'../auth/auth.service';

@Component({
selector: 'user-profile',
templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.css']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements 
OnInit {


constructor(public auth: AuthService) { 

}

ngOnInit() {
 this.auth.googleLogin();
}

}
```

Don't forget to import the AuthService into the component you're using it in.

You may not be using firebase, but just call the method for google login in your particular auth api in either an OnInit function.  No need to 'have' to click a button to call the method.